# Gradually populate InputStream and return it with SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, inputstream

Consider I have a large amount of csv strings in database and I need to pass them to the client by his request.

A naive way to do this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{user}/ejournal", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/csv")
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> getEJournal(@PathVariable Long userId) {
    final byte[] documentBody = EJournal
            .findByUser(userId)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
            .getBytes();
    return new ResponseEntity(
            new ByteArrayResource(documentBody),
            HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

From the client side its straightforward (kotlin code example):

```
val inputStream = eJournalService.getJournal(userId)
inputStream.reader().forEachLine { line -> ... }
```

But I am forced to load the entire data to memory before pass it to the stream and obviously it is not efficient.

So I need somehow to bufferize it to read data with pagination using custom reader and send buffers to client. I thought to implement my own `InputStream` but `InputStream#read()` returns `int` instead of `String` and it is a bit complicated.

Any best practices to do this? I tried to search but there are only examples to pass a picture using stream which is already in memory, not with buffered pagination with sequential database queries after batch sends.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-return-types)

> The following are the supported return types:
>
> [...]
>
> - void if the method handles the response itself (by writing the response content directly, declaring an argument of type ServletResponse / HttpServletResponse for that purpose)
>
> [...]
>
> - A StreamingResponseBody can be returned to write to the response OutputStream asynchronously; also supported as the body within a ResponseEntity.

So you can just do

```
public StreamingResponseBody getEJournal(@PathVariable Long userId) {
    return outputStream -> {
        // write your lines to the outputStream here
    };
}
```

You can also wrote to the stream synchronously by just having the `HttpServletResponse` as argument of your method, and write to its output stream.

Comment: Is it possible to use `StreamingResponseBody` with `@Transactional`? It seems a problem to use it since it is done async.

Comment: Ok, I made it synchronously and no problem so far.